# Pytorch GPU utlilization

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

So I'm currently training my DQN on Atari Breakout (from OpenAI gym). The problem I'm having is that it is very slow, but my GPU does not seem to be fully utilized. I'm  monitoring it with a tool called `HWMonitor` and also with the `nvidia-smi` command. Any ideas why?

Here are some specs that might be relevant:

```
Python version: 3.7.7
torch version: 1.4.0
gym version: 0.17.2
CUDA version: 11.0
GPU: GTX 980 founders edition
CPU: Inte Core i7 4790K
```

And here is some insight into my DQN:

```
device:cuda
DQN(
  (conv1): Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size=(8, 8), stride=(4, 4))
  (conv2): Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(2, 2))
  (mp1): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  (mp2): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  (lin1): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=256, bias=True)
  (lin2): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=4, bias=True)
)
optimizer: Adam (
Parameter Group 0
    amsgrad: False
    betas: (0.9, 0.999)
    eps: 1e-08
    lr: 0.001
    weight_decay: 0
)
gamma: 0.95
epsilon_decay: 0.99
epsilon_min: 0.01
obs_space: [110, 84]
trainig_batchsize: 32
```

Here you can see how my monitoring looks while training with the GPU:
[image: Monitoring]

One more thing that might be important. For some reason training with the CPU is faster then with the GPU. These results are an average over 30 minutes of training. I can't explain why my CPU is faster so if anybody has a clue, I would definitely like to hear it.

```
GPU took 353 seconds for 1000 minibatches
CPU took 148 seconds for 1000 minibatches
```

If any of my code is needed to further inspect my problem please let me know.

EDIT:
I'm now thinking of using cloud GPU services, more specific Linode. The only thing that worries me is that the cause of my problem lies in my code. Thus using a cloud GPU service would not be very smart.

Comment: So you load your model on the gpu and your data?

Comment: Yes everything (model, inputs, ...) is loaded on the GPU, the first line where it says `device: cuda` is autogenerated and prints the device that is being used (i.e. the device where the model and the data is loaded on).

Comment: ye but don't you need to add a line with model.to(device)?

Comment: Yes I have, as you can see in this snippet of my code:


`self.dqn = DQN(self.obs_space, self.action_space, channels_in, channels_inbetween, 
                       channels_out, kernels_conv, strides_conv, kernels_pooling,
                       neurons_linear_layer).to(self.device)`

Comment: have you tried to change the device to cpu and check if it is slower?

Comment: Remember that GPU is for parallel calculations, while it is very slow for sequential ones. In contrast, CPU is good for sequential calculations and slow for parallel ones. So, be sure that you don't do any sequential calculations on GPU (some pre-processing or data cleaning, or smth other)

Comment: I would reiterate that you should make sure everything is on the GPU. Pytorch is a bit quirky for instance I think you have to do `model = model.to(device)`, not just `model.to(device)`. Also, maybe try increasing your batch size until you are getting out of memory errors, then decreasing the size. Larger batch sizes tend to be slightly more efficient time-wise

Answer (score 0):

Even though the following is technically not making it 'faster', in the sense of changing/optimizing the code, I still wanted to present it as an answer to my question.

A solution for me was using [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/). A online notebook, very similar to jupyter notebook, but with a crucial difference, when using the notebook you have access to Google's computing resources (e.g. you can use a high end GPU, for free!).

In my case this was a overall speed-up. But even if you do have quite a good GPU at home, you can still use this to let's say test two different sets of hyperparametes simultaneously.